# Replace multiple `summarize`statements by function

Tags: r, function, tidyverse, summarize

I'm currently repeating a lot code, since I need to `summarize` always the same columns for different groups. How can I do this effectively by writing the `summarize` function (which is always the same) only once, but define the output name and `group_by` arguments case by case?

A minimum example:

```r
col1 <- c("UK", "US", "UK", "US")
col2 <- c("Tech", "Social", "Social", "Tech")
col3 <- c("0-5years", "6-10years", "0-5years", "0-5years")
col4 <- 1:4
col5 <- 5:8

df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)

result1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  summarize(sum1 = sum(col4, col5))

result2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(col2, col3) %>% 
  summarize(sum1 = sum(col4, col5))

result3 <- df %>% 
  group_by(col1, col3) %>% 
  summarize(sum1 = sum(col4, col5))
```

Comment: the `ddply` function is more succinct than `group_by %>% summarise`. You can re-write the first one as `ddply(df, .(col1, col2), summarise, sum1=sum(col5, col5))`. Doesn't answer your actual question but will cut down the number of lines you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `purrr::partial` in these situations :

```
library(purrr)
summarize45 <- partial(summarize, sum1 = sum(col4, col5))

result1b <- df %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2) %>%
  summarize45()

identical(result1, result1b)
# [1] TRUE
```

Or pushing it further :

```
gb_df <- partial(group_by, df)

result1c <- gb_df(col1, col2) %>% summarize45()

identical(result1, result1c)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: this is awesome @Moody_Mudskipper. exactly what I need, reduced my code immediately to 1/6 and I've not even half the work done. would give you more than +1 if I could.

Answer (score 5):

Using *combn*:

```
combn(colnames(df)[1:3], 2, FUN = function(x){
  df %>% 
    group_by(.dots = x) %>% 
    summarize(sum1 = sum(col4, col5))
  }, simplify = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

To use dplyr in own functions, you can use tidy evaluation. The reason for this is the way dplyr evaluates dplyr code, something called non standard evaluation, which wraps everything what does not behave like normal R Code. I recommend to read this:

https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/modifying-inputs.html#modifying-quoted-expressions

```
summarizefunction <- function(data, ..., sumvar1, sumvar2) {

    groups <- enquos(...)
    sumvar1 <- enquo(sumvar1)
    sumvar2 <- enquo(sumvar2)

    result <- data %>%
        group_by(!!!groups) %>%
        summarise(sum1 = sum(!!sumvar1, !!sumvar2))
    return(result)
}

summarizefunction(df, col1, col2, sumvar1 = col4, sumvar2 = col5)
```

You can use the `enquo` keyword to wrap quote parameters which prevents them from being evaluated immediately. This you can use the `!!` (called bang bang) operator to unquote the parameter. I think this is the most flexible and reuseable solution, even when you have to write some more initial code.

Comment: This approach seems to be the most fitting one for me. Only one question: I have hundreds of different veriables to sum, divide etc. is there a way not to type/copy all of them in the `function()` part?

Comment: My number of combinations of groups is much less (8).

Comment: I would recommend you have a look at the reshape2 package. This way you could restructure your dataset in a tidy long format. For example: `reshape2::melt(df)`. Think about the `split` function then, which converts your long df in a list of smaller df´s. Then use the `lapply` function in combination witht the `summarizefunction` . Aggregating over mutiple columns is almost always a "not so nice" idea. 
If you like my solution, please accept my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you'll need to evaluate the variables with a function as such:

```
library(tidyverse)
res_func <- function(x, y){
  df %>% 
  group_by(!!as.symbol(x), !!as.symbol(y)) %>% 
  summarize(sum1 = sum(col4, col5))
}
```

works a charm:

```
res_func("col1", "col2")

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   col1 [2]
  col1  col2    sum1
  <fct> <fct>  <int>
1 UK    Social    10
2 UK    Tech       6
3 US    Social     8
4 US    Tech      12
```

We can use `assign` to create a function that names your frame against the parameters you've passed in through the function:

```
res_func2 <- function(x, y){
  assign(paste0("result_", x, y),
         df %>% 
           group_by(!!as.symbol(x), !!as.symbol(y)) %>% 
           summarize(sum1 = sum(col4, col5)), 
         envir = parent.frame())
}
```

This creates a new df called `result_col1col2` by simply running `res_func2("col1", "col2")`

```
> result_col1col2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   col1 [2]
  col1  col2    sum1
  <fct> <fct>  <int>
1 UK    Social    10
2 UK    Tech       6
3 US    Social     8
4 US    Tech      12
```

Comment: It would look simpler, if you pass one arg to the function. `res_func <- function(x){
  df %>% 
    group_by(!!as.symbol(x)) %>% 
    summarize(sum1 = sum(col4, col5))
}
`

Comment: would that easily be assigned to the name of a new df as requested?

Comment: Yes, `paste(x, collapse = "_")`